# How to create User mongodb with specify action

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My db have those Collection :
users , transactions, balances,...
Each collection manager by one VPS. How can i create user for each collection with specify action?
Example VPS A can read only collection user but can't read password field which is have in users.
VPS B can read / create collection balances but can't edit or delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [create a Role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/), then you can [grant privileges](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantPrivilegesToRole/) to it.

However, you cannot specify privileges for individual fields. You can set it only on database and/or collection level.

Example:

```
use admin
db.createRole(
   {
      role: "VPS_A",
      roles: [],
      privileges: [
         { resource: { db: "db", collection: "user" }, actions: ["find"] }
      ]
   }
)

db.createRole(
   {
      role: "VPS_B",
      roles: [],
      privileges: [
         { resource: { db: "db", collection: "balances" }, actions: ["find", "insert"] }
      ]
   }
)

db.createRole(
   {
      role: "VPS_ReadAll",
      roles: [],
      privileges: [
         // Can read ANY collection in db
         { resource: { db: "db", collection: "" }, actions: ["find"] }
      ]
   }
)

db.grantRolesToUser("<username>", ["VPS_A", "VPS_B"])
```

Mongo also provides [Built-In Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/). In order to grant `read`  privileges on all collections of a database you could also grant:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("<username>", [{ role: "read", db: "db" }])
```